# How to create SharePoint 2010 webapplication using SharePoint Web services?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

How to create SharePoint 2010 webapplication using SharePoint Web services using C#. Any code snippet for this ? and Which ShrePoint web service need to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a web service that will create Web Applications.

The closest is the Central Administration [Admin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/administration.admin%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service that allows you to create a Site Collection.

Comment: So what should be the work around. I think to prepare the custom web service with Sharpoint API/SDK would better. is this right way ?

Comment: Creating a custom web service would probably be your only option. But is it really necessary? How many web applications are you going to be creating remotely on the particular server that hosts your custom web service? Will your web service include the appropriate security? A web application creates an IIS website with its own port and configuration. I can see having web services to create web sites and site collections, but I don't know of many SP farms that have so many web applications that a custom web service is needed. Central administration should be sufficient.

Comment: Indeed, It is not about to use of Central Administration. in fact it is about to make flexible SharePoint via another languages. so that SharePoint Scope should enlarge with langues like Java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this through web services, but you can do it in C# using the [SPWebApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.aspx) object.  You need to create a SPWebApplicationBuilder for the SPFarm and then set the settings for your new SPWebApplication.

This page has some code samples on [How to Create SPWebApplication](http://www.anmolrehan-sharepointconsultant.com/2011/09/how-to-create-spwebapplication.html)